# Surface area of cone without calculus

Tags: geometry

Let $l$ be the length of a cone's lateral and $r$ be the radius of its base. The cone's surface area (excluding the base) is  $\pi rl$.

Briefly googling, most proofs I see simply claim that if you make a cut in the cone from the base to the vertex and "open up" the cone, you get a sector of the circle, with radius $l$ and arc length $2\pi r$. And so the sector's area and hence also the cone's surface area is $$\frac{2\pi r}{2\pi l} \times \pi l^2 = \pi rl.$$

$$$$

But how are we so sure that "cutting and opening up" the cone gives us a sector of a circle? Is there a way to prove this more rigorously?

(Or perhaps there is still some other proof that likewise does not rely on calculus.)

Comment: the distance from the cone's tip to all points of the base is constant, hence those points are a sector of a circle. You can also compute the surface area using Pappus' theorems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus's_centroid_theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a visual proof by rearrangment: [image]